# Asymptotically analyzing growth rate of matrix entries

Tags: linear-algebra, asymptotics

I have the matrix $M=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}$,

and I am trying to find asymptotic bounds for the entries in the matrix as we take $M$ to the $k$th power for $k>1$. It's pretty easy to show that each entry of $M^k$ does not exceed $2^{k-2}$.  The Perron-Frobenius theorem tells us something about the exponential growth rate of the matrix in terms of the eigenvalue with the largest absolute value. Is it possible to get closer? Possibly an expression that is asymptotically equivalent to the entries?

Comment: Matrix exponential?

Comment: @Wuestenfux By matrix exponential you mean $e^A$ for some square matrix $A$? I am not very familiar with those, other than the limited experience I had with them in ODEs II. How would a matrix exponential help?

Comment: Indeed, ${\rm exp}(A)$ or ${\rm exp}(tA)$ which gives for $t\geq 0$ a continuous time Markov chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$M^3$ is a positive matrix, therefore $M$ is primitive and $M^k$ is asymptotically equivalent to $\lambda^k A$ according to the Perron-Frobenius theorem. Let $r$ be the real root of $r^3 + r^2 - 1$, $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$ the eigenvectors of $M$ and $M^t$ corresponding to $r + 1$, then
$$M^k \sim \frac {(r + 1)^k} {\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf w} \mathbf v \mathbf w^t =
\frac {(r + 1)^k} {3 - r^2}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  r^2 & r^2 & r^3 & r \\
  r^3 & r^3 & r^4 & r^2 \\
  r^2 & r^2 & r^3 & r \\
  r & r & r^2 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Wow, that's really neat, and exactly what I was looking for, I have a question though. Why are you using $r+1$ instead of $r$?

Comment: Just to make the matrix entries more compact :).

Answer (score 3):

You may prove by mathematical induction that for each $n\ge2$,
$$
M^n=\pmatrix{
a_n&a_n&b_{n-1}&b_n\\
b_{n-1}&b_{n-1}&a_{n-1}&a_n\\
a_n&a_n&b_{n-1}&b_n\\
b_n&b_n&a_n&a_{n+1}\\
}
$$
where
$$
\pmatrix{a_1\\ b_0\\ a_0}=\pmatrix{1\\ 0\\ 0},
\quad \pmatrix{a_{n+1}\\ b_n\\ a_n}
=\underbrace{\pmatrix{1&1&0\\ 0&1&1\\ 1&0&0}}_A\pmatrix{a_n\\ b_{n-1}\\ a_{n-1}}\text{ for } n\ge1.
$$
It follows that both $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$ are increasing sequences with $b_n\le a_{n+1}$ for every $n$. Therefore the maximum entry of $M^n$ is $a_{n+1}$, which is the top left entry of $A^n$. Hence you may diagonalise $A$ to find $a_{n+1}$.

More specifically, you can diagonalise $A$ as $PDP^{-1}$, where $D=\operatorname{diag}(\rho(A),\lambda,\bar{\lambda})$ is the eigenvalue matrix and the columns of $P$ are the corresponding eigenvectors of $A$. Scale the first column of $P$ so that $P(1,1)=1$. The first row of $P$ and the first column of $P^{-1}$ are then $(1,w,\bar{w})$ and $(x,z,\bar{z})^\top$ respectively for some real number $x$ and some complex numbers $w$ and $z$. Numerically, we have $x\approx0.41150,\ \rho(A)\approx1.75488$ and it also happens that $|\lambda|=\rho(A)-1<1$. Hence
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}=(A^n)_{11}
&=x\rho(A)^n + 2\Re(wz\lambda^n),\\
&\sim x\rho(A)^n\\
&=0.41150\times1.75488^n.
\end{align}

Comment: Can you now say, that $a_{n+1} \sim 1.75488^n$? I have a general square matrix of size $2^p \times 2^p$ with the same properties as the matrix in my question, and I am looking to evaluate a sum of select entries as they tend to infinity. Ideally I would want an exact formula for each entry, but that's too much to ask for with such a big matrix. The next best thing is a formula who when you divide by an entry and take the limit as $n\to \infty$ you get $1$. Would that be possible?

Comment: @ultrainstinct We have $a_{n+1}\sim0.41150\times1.75488^n$, i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{0.41150\times1.75488^n}=1$. I don't think this can be generalised to other matrices, as the recurrence relation here is specific to your $M$.